# Is there a way to boot from usb through grub menu?

Tags: dual-boot, usb, windows-10

I am using dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10. There is a problem which I cannot boot to my normal Windows, and am trying to recover it via USB stick. However, even if I change the boot order, the grub menu still displaying and I have no option to boot from USB.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/349633/boot-from-usb-using-grub

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes there is a way.
First make sure you have secure boot disabled from the firmware settings. (The menu that opens when you press f2 during boot)
Then follow the following steps:

- Press c when in grub menu to open command line
- press `ls` to list all partitions in all hard drives

my output was as follows:

```
grub>ls 
(hd0) (hd0,gpt1) (hd1) (hd1,gpt8) (hd1,gpt7) (hd1,gpt6) (hd1,gpt5) (hd1,gpt4) (hd1,gpt3) (hd1,gpt2) (hd1,gpt1)
```

This clearly shows that my usb drive is hd0.

- type `ls (hd0,gpt1)` to confirm:

Output is as follows:

```
grub>ls (hd0,gpt1) 
Partition hd0,gpt1: Filesystem type fat - Label `CES_X64FREV`, UUID 4099-DBD9 Partition start-512 Sectors...
```

> Inplace of `(hd0,gpt1)` type the address of first partition of usb disk e.g: `(hd1,gpt1)` or `(hd2,gpt1)`. According to output of `ls` command.

We need the UUID shown in the above line

- Note the UUID of you usb drive.
- Type the following commands one by one.

  ```
  insmod part_gpt
  insmod fat
  insmod search_fs_uuid
  insmod chain
  search --fs-uuid --set=root 409-DBD9
  ```

> In place of 4099-DBD9, write UUID which you noted down earlier.

- Now we select the efi file to boot from. Type the following:

  ```
  chainloader /efi/boot/bootx64.efi
  ```
- Finally type `boot`

That's it, That should boot the usb drive.

Comment: Google is the answer!

Comment: Worked for booting a Mint 19 tara USB stick after many other approaches failed!  Amazing!

Comment: Should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: It works! but I had to doing some dancing to get there. Not sure how the ls command "clearly" shows which is which. I ended up doing "ls (hd0)" which gave a size that matched my usb disk size to confirm. Then I used the "ls" command again with a tab complete to find that (hd0,msdos2) contained the /efi/boot/bootx64.efi path: "ls (hd0,msdos2)/efi/boot/bootx64.efi" I could then get the UUID and follow the rest of the steps.

Comment: /efi/boot/bootx64.efi ... file not found ... help please

Comment: Thanks man, finally this worked after trying many things in the whole day.

Comment: If you get file not found could be all uppercase. Do an ls to see