# Missing operating system. error: unknown filesystem grub rescue

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub2, filesystem, chroot

I was installing [hyperledger fabric](https://www.hyperledger.org/projects/fabric), on Ubuntu 18.04.3 Desktop, through sudo -E, of this file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh and of another similar one.

But after installation, which seemed gone fine, I'm not able to use Ubuntu anymore, and when rebooting only an orange screen appears.

Through the iso-image usb, I accessed "Try Ubuntu" option, opened a terminal, and installed Boot-Repair tool.

Here the Boot-Repair Report I got: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KVg3BCSGpd/

Trying to follow the indications found here: [Is there a way to boot from usb through grub menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/947409/is-there-a-way-to-boot-from-usb-through-grub-menu)
and here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P3O_FjPu7vw

I edited:

```
grub rescue> ls
(hd0) (hd0, msdos1) (hd1) (hd1,msdos1)
grub rescue> ls (hd0)/
error: unknown filesystem
grub rescue> ls(hd0,msdos1)/
error: unknown filesystem
grub rescue> ls (hd1)/
error: unknown filesystem
grub rescue> ls (hd1,msdos1)/
error: unknown filesystem

grub rescue> set
cmdpath=(hd0)
prefix=(hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub
```

But the Boot-Repair says:

```
sda1:       

    File system:       LVM2_member
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb1: 

    File system:       LVM2_member
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

ubuntu-vg-root: 

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab 
                   /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img

    ubuntu-vg-swap_1: 

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

    Drive/Partition Info: 

      Drive: sda 
      Disk /dev/sda: 232.9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
      Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
      Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
      I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
      Disklabel type: dos

      Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id 
      System

      /dev/sda1      2,048   488,396,799   488,394,752  8e  Linux LVM
```

In a terminal got with "Try Ubuntu" (iso image usb) I tried with sudo update-grub :

```
ubuntu@ubuntu: ~$ sudo update-grub
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of '/cow'
```

I then followed this indications: 
[Failed to get canonical path of /cow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254491/failed-to-get-canonical-path-of-cow)

I got then 'LVM2_member' :

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mkdir /mnt/chroot
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/chroot
mount: /mnt/chroot: unkown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'
```

But with vgdisplay

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo vgdisplay
  -- Volume group --
  VG Name                   ubuntu-vg
  System ID
  Format                    lvm2
  Metadata Areas            2
  Metadata Sequence No      5
  VG Access                 read/write
  VG Status                 resizable
  MAX LV                    0
  Cur LV                    2
  Open LV                   0
  Max PV                    0
  Cur PV                    2
  Act PV                    2
  VG Size                   <465,77 GiB
  PE Size                   4.00 MiB
  VG UUID                   frpHze-BaQY-T18Q-u5dc-TJH2-NNyp-1T6SsT

  ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lvscan
    ACTIVE    '/dev/ubunstu-vg/root' [<463.93 GiB] inherit
    ACTIVE    '/dev/ubuntu-vg/swap_1' [980.00 MiB] inherit
```

In a terminal with "Try Ubuntu" offered by the iso-image usb I tried:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo su
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# mount /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /mnt
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# cd /mnt
root@ubuntu:/mnt# mount -t devtmpfs none dev
root@ubuntu:/mnt# mount -t sysfs none sys
root@ubuntu:/mnt# mount -t proc proc proc
root@ubuntu:/mnt# chroot .
chroot: failed to run command 'bin/bash': No such file or directory

root@ubuntu:/mnt# ls -lah /bin grep bash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1.1M Jun 6 2019 bash
```

Looking at these indications: 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/338280/chroot-doesnt-find-bin-bash?rq=1

I read that it might be that "The file filename or a script or ELF interpreter does not exist, or a shared library needed for file or interpreter cannot be found". But how to practically resolve it?

Update:

perhaps the brutal-force copy of the entire /bin directory preserving all links into /mnt had made /bin/bash visible and usable by chroot:
    https://drive.google.com/open?id=13a9bgNYzvCzUC6dO1wR5Wx7KlvojVMri

But I got this error:

```
mapdevfs: error while loading shared libraries: libdebian-
installaer.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or 
directory
```

I tried again to re-install grub and got this error:

```
root@ubuntu:/# grub-install /dev/sda
Installing for i386-pc platform.
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device 
  scanning
  Installation finished. No error reported.

root@ubuntu:/# grub-install /dev/sdb
Installing for i386-pc platform
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device 
  scanning
```

Installation finished. No error reported

https://drive.google.com/open?id=13bHrF1UGcWicVL4aXQfJm4N2odKdWp0B

This is the result of my very last attempt to update grub:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo su
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# mount /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /mnt
mount: /mnt: /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root already mounted on /mnt.
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# cd /mnt
root@ubuntu:/mnt# mount -t devtmpfs none dev
mount: /mnt/dev: none already mounted on /mnt/dev.
root@ubuntu:/mnt# mount -t sysfs none sys
mount: /mnt/sys: none already mounted on /mnt/dev.
root@ubuntu:/mnt# mount -t proc proc proc
mount: /mnt/proc: proc already mounted on /proc.
root@ubuntu:/mnt# chroot .
root@ubuntu:/# update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-28-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-28-generic
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-23-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-23-generic
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
mapdevfs: error while loading shared libraries: libdebian-installer.so.4:  
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
log-output: error while loading shared libraries: libdebian-
installer.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
mapdevfs: error while loading shared libraries: libdebian-installer.so.4:     
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
mapdevfs: error while loading shared libraries: libdebian-installer.so.4:    
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
mapdevfs: error while loading shared libraries: libdebian-installer.so.4:     
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
mapdevfs: error while loading shared libraries: libdebian-installer.so.4: 
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

BIG UPDATE: rebooting the system now works fine.
LESSON LEARNED: when ever install something new, check and verify it might produce some side-effects

Looking forward to your kind help.
Marco