Upgrade to 24.04 LTS failed, what is the next step in recovery mode?
In recovery mode, after a failed system upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04, the photo below shows the information that appears on the screen. There appears to be no access the command line (I tried Ctrl+Alt+F3). I would appreciate any advice on what to do next. This is an iMac from 2015.


As the upgrade has failed the best quickest and probably the only choice is to install a fresh Ubuntu 24.04 and then restore the data backup you made before the upgrade.

Thanks @DavidDE , can you point me to how to install from a  Live USB using Grub 2.06?

You do not use Grub you boot from the live media. Is this not how you did the original install of the previous version? https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

Thank you @user535733, can you help me identify the USB drive so that I can point Grub to it?
I have been looking at this post as a guide: https://askubuntu.com/questions/947409/is-there-a-way-to-boot-from-usb-through-grub-menu
To find my USB, I use the ls command, and see this list, and would like to know which is the USB:
proc, memdisk, hd0, hd0-gpt3, hd0-gpt2, hd0-gpt1, hd1, hd1-msdos1, hd2, hd3, hd3-gpt-2, hd3-gpt-1
What am I looking for?

Thank you @DavidDE. Install with Live media is not working this time. It opens a Grub menu, with no option to use the USB at all. Advanced Options leads to a choice of kernel or recovery modes and then to the screen in the photo. At that point it is stuck, and I can only power off. So my only route would seem to involve commands in the rescue Grub.

Reaching GRUB means one of two possibilities. 1) You did not boot from the LiveUSB at all, and the system is still booting from the HDD, or 2) Your LiveUSB has been mis-made and is unbootable.

@user535733, I have found it, by going through each partition with ‘ls’:
(hd0,gpt1): Filesystem type  iso9660 - Label ‘Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS amd64’

Update: using The_Loud.speaker’s answer in the link posted above, I succeeded in getting into the 24.04 live user environment via the Live USB. However, it kept freezing. I tried both installing from the GUI and opening a terminal. Eventually  it returned me to a black screen and a Grub menu. So it’s back to square 1!

The procedure that worked to resolve this was:
Use Live media and re-install the previous ubuntu system (in my case this was 22.04.2 LTS) rather than the targeted upgrade version (24.04 LTS).
Steps taken to get access to the Live USB are set out in the answer given by The_Loud.speaker in this post:
Is there a way to boot from usb through grub menu?
Note: These steps need to be followed carefully because it was only possible to use a limited range of bash commands. The screen stated: Minimal BASH-like editing is supported.
This allowed me then to use the GUI to re-install the 22.04.2 LTS system.
I then followed the upgrade steps when prompted, and 24.04 LTS was successfully installed.
